# How do you use inverse properties in an Elasticsearch GraphDB connector?

Tags: elasticsearch, graphdb

e.g. does something like this work:
  {
      "fieldName": "aField",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://example.com/y/z/propertyA",
        "^http://example.com/y/z/propertyB"
      ]
  },
      ...

Answer (score 0):

In GraphDB 8.x, Connectors does not support indexing of subjects for a given object. The rationale behind this design decision is to keep all indexes smaller in the case of longer property paths.

For repositories with configured inference (i.e. the ruleset is not empty), I recommend declaring an `owl:inverseOf` property like:

```
:PropertyB owl:inverseOf :PropertyInverseOfB.
```

`owl:inverseOf` will create a new implicit triple with the direction from the object to the subject, so you can put:

```
{ 
  "fieldName": "aField", 
  "propertyChain": 
     [ "http://example.com/y/z/propertyA", "http://example.com/y/z/propertyInverseOfB" ]
}
```

For repositories with empty ruleset, you would need to change your modelling and create a new triple in the opposite direction.